# SASS - set relative value

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Is it possible to set a relative value to a property? Something that would make the following compilation works:

**SCSS source file:**

```
.class {

  font-size: 10pt;

  &.subclass {
    font-size: +2;
  }

}
```

**CSS result file:**

```
.class {
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.class.subclass {
  font-size: 12pt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable:

```
$size: 10pt;

.class {
  font-size: $size;

  &.subclass {
    font-size: $size + 2pt;
  }
}
```

Comment: My necessity is more complex, the example is merely illustrative. I need to make the background-position of a Compass generated sprite to move 1 pixel up on IE8 only.

Comment: Just discovered that the Sprite generator have a offset mechanism: `my-sprite(icon-name, $offset-x: -1, $offset-y: -2)`. Still curious if there is a way to use relative values.

Comment: @CaioToOn--I don't believe there is any way to access the properties without those properties being set in a variable as hopper has shown. Now, the variable could be local (contained and set _within_ the `.class` definition, as opposed to outside it like hopper showed) and then used in the nested `.subclass` call.